# Open set and sequences in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $A$ is an open set if, and only if, the following condition is satisfied: " if a sequence $(x_n)$ converges for a point $a \in A$, then $x_n \in A$ for all $n$ sufficiently large".

I have doubts in the second implication $( \Leftarrow )$. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $x_n$ a sequence of real numbers such thar $x_n \to a \in A$ and for all sufficiently large $n$ we have that $x_n \in A$. But I can't find an $ \varepsilon$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(a) \subset A$ because I don't see why my $A$ cannot be $[a, +\infty)$, for example. I know that, if this $\varepsilon$ exists, it will come from the definition of this limit.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're having trouble because you're forgetting the fact that the statement must hold for all seuquences converging to $a$. In your example, the sequence $x_n=a-1/n$ does not satify the condition for $[a, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Try by contradiction. That is, if $a_n\to a$ as $n\to\infty$, we know from the definition that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Now, if $A$ is *not* open, then can you construct a sequence converging to $a$ such that none of the points are in $A$? This provides a contradiction to the hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you very much. As @Mateus Sampaio said, I forgot that this must hold for all sequences that converges for an element in $A$

Comment: @Giiovanna: Glad we were able to help :)